# Why is there a delay for the transition of my pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I need to animate both of the element and its pseudo element.

Then I noticed, when I hover, everything is fine. But then I stop hovering, the `Home` animates first and after that, the pseudo element `Link` starts animating.

Why it behaves like this? Is there a way to make them animate simultaneously?

Here's a simplified recreation of my problem:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
}

a::before {
  content: 'Link:';
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">Home</a>
```

I'm using MacOS with Chrome `Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

If you can't reproduce the problem, here's a screengrab of it:

[image: glitch]

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Windows with Chrome, but *not* with Firefox. Would assume it's down to the way that browsers handle transitions on hyperlinks.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That's so weird, I tried FireFox and it works fine, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also assigned the default values ​​to `::before` and works fine. I think it trying to inherit the default values and it's confusing.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
}

a::before {
  content: 'Link:';
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: blue;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">Home</a>
```

Comment: Also, the color transition is delayed. Maybe I just need to define all the default properties that I need to animate.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no default `font-size` for the pseudo element so the pseudo element will `inherit` the font-size of the `a`. Here is what is happening:

1. we initially have both element at `font-size` `X` (`X` is based on your other properties, `16px` here)
2. On hover the pseudo element will have `32px` and `a` will have `48px`
3. when you unhover (and here is the trick) the pseudo element will inherit for a moment the `font-size` of the `a` (`48px`) so your transition will be from `32px` to `48px - y` where `y` is changing du to the transition applied to `a` until the `48px - y` is back to `X`

Same logic apply with coloration because it's also inherited. Simply set a default `font-size` and `color`

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
}

a:hover::before {
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
}

a::before {
  content: 'Link:';
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size:16px;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But that doesn't explain why it works well in Firefox. Maybe they use different techniques to interpret the style inheritance?

Comment: @HaoWu I would say it doesn't work well in Firefox. You need to make the difference between how you want it to work and how it should work. For me it's working well on Chrome as I explained and Firefox is failing or doing something else with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on mouseover it's a bit ugly but at least it's working smoothly

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  content: 'Link:';
/*   transition: all 1s; */
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
}
a:hover::before {
  transition: all 1s;
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">Home</a>
```